# Distinguish between null and missing field when mapping (POCO) with mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, c#-4.0, poco

Lets say i have a class

```
 class Person
{
    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("age")]
    public int? Age { get; set; }
}
```

then in mongo I have

[{
    "name": "Jan",
    "age": null
}, {
    "name": "San",
    "age": 20
}, {
    "age": 20
}]

Then call

```
collection.Find(filter).Project<Person>(projections).ToListAsync()
```

and then I get back

[{
    "Name": "Jan",
    "Age": null
}, {
    "Name": "San",
    "Age": 20
}, {
    "Name": null,
    "Age": 20
}]

Is there a way to see if the field was missing and not just get null back